# Webbrowser control stopped showing instagram

Tags: c#, instagram, webbrowser-control

I have windows forms app which has a webrowser control. I am using it to login to instagram. Until today it worked just fine. Today it started to give the script error and stuck at the splash screen.

[image: the error and where it stcuk]

To see if it is because I unknowingly did something on the project, I even created a brand new solution with a web browser and only changed its url to instagram and it gave the same error.
So that made me think two possibilities.
1- As in lots of questions, it is browser version emulation thing, which is solved by reg update. I tried all didnt work. And my webbrowser works in latest version anyway, as you can see in textbox on top right corner. but somehow maybe I didnt apply the solution correctly.
2- Instagram itself somehow detected webbrowser access and blocks me.

If anybody can help, it will be highly ağpprecaited.

Comment: The WebBrowser control uses Internet Explorer, whose development stopped in 2015 and thus doesn’t support modern JavaScript.

Comment: Instagram uses OAuth2 authentication. To login with a desktop app you need have an redirect URI which is called by the auth server when the uses has successfully logged in. Thus the approach is start local minimum HTTP server (C# HttpListener class) which receives the auth response, call the authentication URI of Instagram (appended with the redirect URI) with Process.Start which will start the default browser, user logs in, Instagram page calls your redirect URI and you know get a code to exchange for an auth token. Example: https://github.com/googlesamples/oauth-apps-for-windows

Comment: @ckuri - it doesn ot open the instagram site at all. it stucks where it shows. I could not even reach to login scream.